# Python reference variable in outer class

Tags: python, oop

How can I assign a variable from an outer class to the inner? Here is my best attempt:

```
in [1]: class one:
   ...:     x = 1
   ...:     class two:
   ...:         y = x
   ...:         
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

I am confused as to why this doesn't work, but Python has no problem with this syntax:

```
In [1]: x = 1
In [2]: class one:
   ...:     y = x
   ...:     class two:
   ...:         z = x
   ...:         

In [3]: one.two.z
Out[3]: 1
```

Comment: How can I rephrase this question? Edit: Thanks Jeremy Banks I now see this is an outer class.

Comment: Why are you even putting one class inside another? There's almost never a reason to do that in Python.

Comment: Related: [Nested Python class needs to access variable in enclosing class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391645/nested-python-class-needs-to-access-variable-in-enclosing-class)

Comment: I am experimenting with different openmdao configurations

Comment: @kilojoules I'm not certain if "outer class" is a formal/standard term for this, but it's one I've seen used elsewhere and is hopefully a bit clearer. I always get Python's behaviour in this context mixed up; it's not very obvious.

Comment: In the second example, `'x' is not defined` within the scope of `y`. In the first example, `x` is defined in the global scope.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When a class definition is encountered Python will execute the body without second thought.

First, it will execute `class one`, while executing the body (and before actually creating the class), it will encounter `class two` so it will execute that.

Inside `class two` it will see a reference to `one` which still does not exist, hence a `NameError` will be raised.

One simple way to see the difference in the way Python treats classes/functions is by wrapping the second class definition inside a function. Since Python only *compiles* functions and doesn't execute them, `class one` is going to get created:

```
class one:
    x = 1
    def wrap():
        class two:
            y = one.x
        one.two = two
```

Now `one` exists as a class. If you execute `one.wrap` the second class definition is going to get executed, the `one` class is going to be found and then, just to follow along with your original example; I set the class `two` as an attribute of `one` to get the same effect you were going for.

As a result, name resolution works fine and class `two` now has an attribute of class `one`:

```
one.wrap()

one.two.y
Out[22]: 1
```

---

**Do Note:** Moving the second class outside of the first class definition works too, but that's besides the point.

Comment: Great! One small note to others - it should be `def wrap(self):`. otherwise it will throw a number of arguments error.

Comment: @kilojoules The `TypeError` is raised if you instantiate. If not you should be good to go. Either way, this example with the nested `class` in the `def` was not meant as something that you should use but more so in order to illustrate how Python *executes classes* vs *compiles functions*.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing makes no sense to me, anyway, you can access outer class's instance variable by passing its instance into inner class. Nested classes are not recommended. You can use `Inheritance` to achieve this.

```
class Outer:
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = 1

    def create_inner(self):
        """passes outer class instance into Inner"""
        return Outer.Inner(self)

    class Inner:
        def __init__(self, outer):
            self._outer = outer
            self._y = self._outer._x

        def print_y(self):
            print self._y


outer = Outer()
inner = outer.create_inner()
inner.print_y()
```

Output:

```
1
```